# XHTML - Two float:right divs ontop of eachother?

Tags: html, xhtml, alignment

I want to put two float:right'ing divs ontop of eachother.

I've tried position:relative; top:-HEIGHTpx; but it seems to be doing nothing (Obviously I didn't put in 'HEIGHT', I put in the actual height

I don't think there's much more necessary detail realy.

Although here's the style attribute of the first element:

```
style="width:750px; margin-right:20px; background-color:#D6D6D6; border:1px solid #8C8C8C; float:right; font-family:arial; height:250px"
```

And the second:

```
style="width:750px; margin-right:20px; background-color:#D6D6D6; border:1px solid #8C8C8C; font-family:arial; height:250px; z-index: 2; float:right;"
```

Putting them inside eachother would be possible but I'm going to be needing to manipulate the left:___px property with javascript so I'd rather leave them as siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use position: absolute and z-index for both divs.

First add to the CONTAINER div (the parent of your two divs):

```
position: relative
```

First div: (removed float, margin-right, added position absolute and z-index)

```
style="width:750px; background-color:#D6D6D6; border:1px solid #8C8C8C; font-family:arial; height:250px; position: absolute; right: 20px; z-index: 1"
```

Second div: (removed float, margin-right, added position absolute and z-index)

```
style="width:750px; background-color:#D6D6D6; border:1px solid #8C8C8C; font-family:arial; height:250px; position: absolute; right: 20px; z-index: 2;"
```

Comment: Your exact solution didn't work, but a small variation did, much appreciated!